# Why does this rule not block all requests?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension to block YouTube as a whole, but it's only blocking some requests. For example, all embedded videos are blocked, but when I go to https://www.youtube.com or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ it'll block only some elements.

https://www.youtube.com as far as I can tell loads everything except for elements loaded due to user navigation--for example, the collapsed hamburger menu doesn't load when clicked.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "*://*.youtube.com/*",
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**rules.json**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "youtube.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Looks like a bug because if you add `"resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]` the site will be blocked.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the help! Following your advice, I've explicitly declared all the resource types in the rules.json. All youtube.com urls were blocked as a result, however simply <https://youtube.com> still loads, albeit barely anything is displayed.

Comment: In my test using the code in my comment above the site was blocked.

Comment: @wOxxOm I made a new Chrome profile and the extension has expected behavior there. Perhaps another extension was interfering with it. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that other extensions aren't interfering with it. I disabled all of them except for this one and it still does not result in the expected behavior in my normal Chrome profile.

Comment: This is still a bug in Chrome to me so it's best if you could report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some pages are cached, bypassing the declarativeNetRequest rules

Refer to [Interaction with Cached Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#interaction-with-cached-pages).

> When rules are applied to browsers with pages in the service worker's cached storage, the browser may ignore the set rule for those specific pages until the cached storage is cleared. This is because cached storage is intended to be persistent, and many features like offline use do not expect the cache to be cleared without also clearing a service worker's registration as well. **For cases when extensions utilizing declarativeNetRequest must be enabled and disabled repeatedly, the chrome.browsingData API may be used to clear the cache to guarantee proper functionality.**

#### Here's a possible solution to clear cache for specific sites upon reload:

background.js:

```
chrome.browsingData.remove(
  {
    // unregister service workers for known websites to redirect/block that use them
    origins: ['https://example.com'],
  },
  {
    serviceWorkers: true,
  }
);
```

Manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```